# Set/unset socks proxy via shell

Tags: macos, shell, proxy, socks-proxy

In OSX Lion I set ssh proxy to connect to work. All I do is

a) in terminal

ssh -D 8080 -f -C -q -N work_host_machine

b) System prefereces, proxy, set socks proxy

Step b) needs to be performed by hand, but can it be set and unset through shell or script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxy Ethernet 127.0.0.1 8080 off
```

...assuming your primary network service is named "Ethernet".  If you need to figure out the service name, it gets a bit more complicated; see [this code snippet](http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1819) for one way to do it.